# Como trocar a chave primária de uma tabela no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

```sql
CREATE TABLE Produto (
  Codigo_Produto INTEGER,
  Descricao_Produto VARCHAR(50),
  Preco_Produto FLOAT,
  PRIMARY KEY (Codigo_Produto)
);

CREATE TABLE Nota_fiscal (
  Numero_NF INTEGER,
  Data_NF DATE,
  Valor_NF FLOAT,
  PRIMARY KEY (Numero_NF)
);

CREATE TABLE Itens (
    Produto_Codigo_Produto INTEGER,
    Nota_fiscal_Numero_NF INTEGER,
    Num_Item INTEGER,
    Qtde_Item INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY(Produto_Codigo_Produto, Nota_fiscal_Numero_NF),
    FOREIGN KEY (Produto_Codigo_Produto) REFERENCES Produto(Codigo_Produto),
    FOREIGN KEY (Nota_fiscal_Numero_NF) REFERENCES Nota_fiscal(Numero_NF)
);
```

Eu to com um problema, eu tenho um exercício q tenho q criar essas 3 tabelas, porém depois eu tenho q realizar a seguinte ação:
"Fazer com que a chave primária da tabela Itens deixe de ser composta por codigo do produto. mais numero da nota fiscal e passe a ser Num_item"
Porém, quando eu tento fazer executar o seguinte código:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Itens DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE Itens
ADD PRIMARY KEY (Num_Item);
```

O mysql me devolve esse erro: "Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of './vendas/#sql-1_11' to './vendas/Itens' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)
"

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que está usando o campo que é *primary key* também como *foreign key*, e dá erro ai.

Você vai ver o erro se tentar fazer o drop/add num único comando assim:

`ALTER TABLE Itens DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (Num_Item);`

O erro será:

> Cannot drop index 'PRIMARY': needed in a foreign key constraint

Em resumo, não pode remover uma *primay key* que está sendo usanda também como *foreign key*.

Para fazer o *drop* da *primary key*, primeiro precisa remover a *foreign key*, então dá mais trabalho isso. Supondo que o modelo esteja correto (as duas *foreign keys*), então vai precisar também excluir antes. Porém, para se excluir uma *foreign key* é preciso saber o nome da *constraint* (toda chave é no final uma *constraint*).

Quem elaborou esse exercício talvez não tenha planejado bem isso, mas é outro assunto... então precisa primeiro mudar a criação das chaves, usando `CONSTRAINT`, de forma que pode lhe dar um nome, e fica fácil excluir depois:

```
CREATE TABLE Itens (
    Produto_Codigo_Produto INTEGER,
    Nota_fiscal_Numero_NF INTEGER,
    Num_Item INTEGER,
    Qtde_Item INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(Produto_Codigo_Produto, Nota_fiscal_Numero_NF)
);

-- ADICIONA AS DUAS FOREIGN KEYS
ALTER TABLE Itens ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Codigo_Produto FOREIGN KEY (Produto_Codigo_Produto) REFERENCES Produto(Codigo_Produto);
ALTER TABLE Itens ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Numero_NF FOREIGN KEY (Nota_fiscal_Numero_NF) REFERENCES Nota_fiscal(Numero_NF);

-- REMOVE AS DUAS FOREING KEYS, DEPOIS A PRIMARY KEY E RECRIA
ALTER TABLE Itens DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_Codigo_Produto;
ALTER TABLE Itens DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_Numero_NF;
ALTER TABLE Itens DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (Num_Item);
```

Note que, com `ADD CONSTRAINT` podemos dar nomes, por exemplo o "fk_Codigo_Produto" e depois fica fácil excluir, o mesmo poderia ser feito com a *primary key* :)

Pode ver um exemplo funcionando aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0ce11)

Uma nota para quem ver essa resposta: é um exercício, num caso real, ao recriar uma *primary key*, que como mencionei é uma *constraint*, a validação será aplicada, ou seja, eram 2 campos e passou a ser 1, se houver registros com valores duplicados não será possível criar a chave. A forma mais comum de fazer nesses casos é:

- Criar uma nova tabela na estrutura correta;
- Inserir os dados nessa nova tabela (SELECT INTO/INSERT FROM SELECT);
- Apagar a tabela antiga;
- Renomear a nova tabela.